# PHP PDO | Calling execute() and fetchAll() of stored procedure call within nested for loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to retrieve a row from my database one a time since I want to retrieve a block of time (specifically for a schedule) for processing within my PHP code. When I execute() and fetchAll() for one time, it works just fine. When I place these two functions within the said for loop, the first iteration works as intended (retrieving the correct row given the said parameter). But for the following iterations, it does not return any value anymore.

Please tell me about the flaws in my utilization of PDO. I am a beginner in PHP PDO's and am still wrapping my head around object-oriented database access.

```
$connection = OpenCon('localhost', 'prof', 'prof_pass', 'school_db'); //Open PDO connection
$query_class = $connection->prepare("CALL school_db.get_class_block(?, ?);");
$query_class->bindParam(1, $day_date_string);
$query_class->bindValue(2, $prof_id);

for ($col = 0; $col < 7; $col++) {
  for ($row = 0; $row < 9; $row++) {
    $day_date_string = $day_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "<br/>$day_date_string<br/>";
    $query_class->execute();
    $m = $query_class->fetchAll();
    echo count($m);
    $day_date->add($date_span->createFromDateString('90 minutes'));  //Add 1.5 hours
  }
  $day_date->add($date_span->createFromDateString('10 hours + 30 minutes')); //Add 9.5 hours to switch the next day
}

CloseCon($connection); //Close connection
```

Comment: `$x` is `true` or `false`, so `$x->fetchAll()` should be causing an error.

Comment: Sorry edited my code. It's still the same scenario, fetchAll() and execute() only works for the first iteration. It doesn't retrieve any row on the following iterations

Comment: No rows returned

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Still not working for me. Using fetchAll() and execute() within the loop with a simple select statement instead of a call works fine though. I'm not sure whether the problem is with the binding or the usage of CALL within the prepare() function

Comment: My test was just with a simple SELECT, let me try `CALL`.

Comment: I already added EXECUTE privilege for the user. I can do an execute() with a CALL statement if it's not in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a [quirk of MySQL](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call), when the query is a `CALL` statement, trying to reuse the statement causes the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

None of the suggestions in the error message actually work. But closing the cursor before calling `execute()` again resolves the problem.

```
for ($col = 0; $col < 7; $col++) {
  for ($row = 0; $row < 9; $row++) {
    $day_date_string = $day_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "<br/>$day_date_string<br/>";
    $query_class->execute();
    $m = $query_class->fetchAll();
    $query_class->closeCursor();
    echo count($m);
    $day_date->add($date_span->createFromDateString('90 minutes'));  //Add 1.5 hours
  }
  $day_date->add($date_span->createFromDateString('10 hours + 30 minutes')); //Add 9.5 hours to switch the next day
}
```

Comment: How do fetchAll() and closeCursor() differ? It resolved my issue to thanks

Comment: `fetchall()` fetches the data, `closeCursor()` tells PDO to free the internal data used to keep track of what it has fetched so far.

Comment: So is it necessary to closeCursor() often or is it always implied when using fetchAll()?

Comment: It's not normally necessary when you've fetched everything. It seems like a bug in MySQL or PDO that you need it here.

Comment: You can always refer to my tutorial for the [explanation](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call) :)

Comment: Thanks, I've linked to it. You might want to incorporate the `closeCursor()` solution, it feels cleaner than `nextRowset()` + `columnCount()`

Comment: I feel rather the opposite. closeCursor() is rather a blunt solution, like cutting one's head off to cure a headache. The nextRowset() is meant for the case, and you don't need the columnCount() call for a simple case like this. I just don't know whether a database would convey anything useful with that extra empty reaultset but if it's the case, nextRowset() would convey this message while closeCursor() wouldn't. And yes - it's a database quirk, not PDO's. Not for the argument sake, I am just sharing the findings I was able to gather on the matter.

Comment: @YourCommonSense OK. In that case, a more logical solution might be to call `nextRowSet()` followed by `fetchAll()`, rather than depend on the second result set being empty so you don't need to fetch anything. `columnCount()` feels like a kludge.

Comment: Yes, exactly but I feel the last fetchAll() call is not necessary, as there are no rows to fetch. In case we are expecting only a single rowset from a stored procedure, all we need is to run the procedure (`query()`), get the results (`fetchAll()`) and then just a single call to `nextRowset()` to fetch that extra empty rowset and clean the results queue, like it shown in the first example in the article.